# Trying to add table name value passed from frontend in INSERT sql query in node.js but it didn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, node.js, express

```
const q = "INSERT INTO ?? (`text`,`url`) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [req.body.text, req.body.url];
    console.log(values);
    console.log([tableName, ...values]); // did not worked
    
    db.query(q, [tableName, values], (err, data) => {})
```

Code I tried I have shown above, I don't understand why it didn't work, I read about SELECT query in it tablename was passed using `??`, but I don't why it didn't work for INSERT query, can any explain why ? and also please what exactly `??` and `?` do here  ?

I got tablename from frontend using req.params and stored in a varibale named as tableName and use its value in taableName but it didn't work, I got the idea to use ?? from an example of SELECT query,
but I don't understand why it didn't work for INSERT query and want to know why?
I was going to use this query to insert data into the table whose name I get from frontend so I don't have to write insert query for every table which has similar columns.

I got the following error:
"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3);

i think you mismatching the columns values